# What is the most effective way of using a MacBook Pro with an external monitor?

Tags: mac, display, hdmi, battery

I have an early-2013 MacBook Pro with Retina Display 15-inch and it has been working amazingly for the past year. I spend around 8 months at school and 4 months at home. In school, I need the laptop during classes with nary an opportunity to charge my MacBook Pro therefore, I need its 6 hour battery life. I cannot compromise on that. However, when I'm home I like to connect it via HDMI to my 1080p Samsung monitor so that I can do my coding and gaming. When I do that, I put the laptop in **clamshell** mode.

Given that the laptop will remain in charge 99% of the day, and keeping the heat issues aside (I have an external cooler and `smcFanControl`), what effect will this have on my battery life ?

What's the most effective way of connecting my Mac to an external monitor without having battery problems ?

Comment: It will have an effect.  If you can configure your laptop not to charge unless you specifically tell it that will help.  The chemical reaction in a laptop has a limited number of reactions.  It does appear you can replace the battery [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1446#Servicing)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the `configuration` ?

Comment: I was speaking in general. One way is to configure it to only charge when the battery truely requires it ( i.e. fully depleeted ).  How you would do this on OS X is well documented.

Comment: [This](https://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html) may be of interest.